# Configure WLAN for RaspberryPI3 using image created with Yocto

Tags: pi-3, yocto, wifi

I have some trouble trying to configure my wlan in my new RaspberryPi3 maybe you can help me.

I created my own image for the RaspberryPI3 using the Yocto Jethro (rpi-basic-image) and  Ubuntu 14.04. It worked and my RaspberryPI3 booted. 
Then I tried to configure my wlan connection. I didn’t touch the file /etc/network/interfaces since it looks good to me :

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  wireless_mode managed
  wireless_essid any
  wpa-driver wext
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The file /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf didn’t exit and I created :

```
network={
  ssid="wlan-name"
  psk="keyHex"
  proto=RSN
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  pairwise=CCMP
  auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Then I tried ifup wlan0 and I got the flag:

```
ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device
```

Do you know what I did wrong or what is missing?
Thank you in advanced

Comment: I'm making the assumption you are using the built in Wi-Fi, and not a wireless adapter?

Comment: The package name has been changed from `linux-firmware-brcm43430` to `linux-firmware-bcm43430`. See here
https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2016-November/033048.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wlan0 is not detected, I had the same issue. I think you didn't load the kernel modules to use the in-built wifi. If you look into the configuration file for the rpi3 in yocto, you have the recipe `linux-firmware-brcm43430` which should be compiled and added into the rootfs.

The kernel modules are .ko files. Find them in your yocto compiled folder.
`<yocto_path>/build/tmp/work/` and add them to your filesystem. Load the module, check you have `wlan0` doing `ifconfig -a`.

Answer (score 3):

The Blog [blog](https://raspinterest.wordpress.com/2017/02/28/configure-wlan0-and-bluetooth-in-yocto-raspberry-pi-3/) has explained it nicely. It worked for me
Here is the instruction as explained in the blog:
Add following line to `build/local.conf`

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " bluez5 bluetooth wifi"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " linux-firmware-bcm43430 bluez5 i2c-tools python-smbus bridge-utils hostapd dhcp-server iptables wpa-supplicant"
```

Add following lines to `bblayers.conf`

```
${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
```

cd to home directory for Yocto

```
cd ~/yocto/
```

Source the build environment script

```
source sources/poky/oe-init-build-env rpi-build
```

Build image with new recipes and features

```
bitbake [image-name]
```

Copy the newly built image in SD card
Boot Raspberry Pi 3 with newly built image.
Edit `wpa_supplicant` file

```
vi /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Change to content to following

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="<SSID_NAME>"
    psk="<PASSWORD>"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Restart Rpi3

```
reboot
```

Log in to Raspberry Pi 3 and configure Wi-Fi

```
ifup wlan0
```